# Excel automatically opens data source when I refresh connection

Tags: vba, excel, data-connections

I have two workbooks on a shared network drive:

- `Workbook A (source: Table with data)`
- `Workbook B (Pivot Table -Connected to Table in Workbook A)`

When a user has workbook A open and another user tries to open workbook B and refreshes the data, it automatically opens workbook A in read-only mode to refresh data. This seems to only happen when workbook A(source) is opened for editing.

How can I prevent this from happening? Would a macro solve this?

Comment: Workbook A would have to be closed for it to not open in read-only mode. As long as nothing in Workbook A needs to be changed, it will still refresh the data in Workbook B whether it's in read-only mode or not.

Comment: I don't want workbook A to open at all when someone else has it opened. The update needs to happen in the background.

Comment: Looking forward to somebody helping with this problem! I have the same situation. My two workbooks are connected with a MS Query connection.

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.Screenupdating = False
 'your code here
Application.Screenupdating = True
```

Comment: Already tried that and the same thing happens. The only way around this I see is "If workbook A is open, Exit Sub Else thisworkbook.refreshall."

Comment: Yes, maybe myBoolean = IsWorkBookOpen("C:\myWorkbook.xlsm") If myBoolean Then Exit Sub Else refreshall